# I can't move my div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm always having trouble with the combination of CSS and JQuery. Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong here? I just want to move my div. Thanks all for the solutions, I'd like to know a little further. How can i move it more than once in different directions?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#hello").mouseenter(function () {
            jQuery("#hello").animate({ left: '150px' }, slow);

        });

    });
</script>


<div id="hello">
    Hello World!
</div>
<style>
    #hello{
        color: gray;
        background-color: gold;
        width: 125px;
        height: 125px;
        position: fixed;
        left: 350px;
        top: 350px;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-color: lavender;
        text-align: center;

    }
</style>
```

Comment: Did you try to set #hello to `position: relative` or `position: absolute`?

Comment: I made a [fiddle for you](https://jsfiddle.net/970Ly6f3/)

Comment: [You don't need jQuery.](http://jsfiddle.net/7wdysxc9/)

Comment: Thanks for the alternative ways also.

Comment: @Vohuman You don't need jQuery, but your example isn't working very well. Move the mouse around over that div. It restarts the animation every time the mouse position changes. You should use the CSS animate

Comment: @JoshStevenson I'm aware of that. It was just an example. It should be noted that jQuery `mouseenter` doesn't work like CSS `:hover` so the above snippet doesn't undo the `mouseenter` effect on `mouseleave`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your div needs a position set when using `left`, `right`, `top` or `bottom` css propertiy, so there will be no change even though your code seems correct.

Try to set a position to your div, for example relative.

```
<style>
#hello{
        color: gray;
        background-color: gold;
        width: 125px;
        height: 125px;
        position: fixed;
        left: 350px;
        top: 350px;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-color: lavender;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
    }
</style>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#hello").mouseenter(function () {
            jQuery("#hello").animate({ left: '150px' }, 'slow');

        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Oh and one more thing please. How can i move it more than once? Like in different directions?

Comment: You can animate it as often as you want to, just write another animation after it. Though i'd recomend using velocity.js if you are planing on doing more animations. It's easier queueable and has a much better performance

Comment: Okay i'll check it out.

Answer (score 5):

If You are using slow/fast option You need to put 'slow' into brackets

```
jQuery("#hello").animate({ left: '150px' }, 'slow');
```

You can set animation time with milliseconds without brackets.

Comment: A default speed will be defined automatically if not supplied.

Answer (score 5):

The duration parameter of your `animate()` is undefined (`Uncaught ReferenceError: slow is not defined`).

It should be either `"slow"`

```
 jQuery("#hello").animate({ left: '150px' }, "slow");
```

or

```
 var slow = 200;
 jQuery("#hello").animate({ left: '150px' }, slow);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mgyqoe3/)** (with error)

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mgyqoe3/1/)** (Updated)

I would recommend the CSS way `:hover` if its just about mouseover event. If there is more functionality to add, this is better.

Comment: A default speed will be automatically defined if missing.

Comment: @JoshStevenson, NO. Though you are right, In this case a wrong/invalid input duration is the problem